# Table cell width in Internet Explorer

Tags: html-table, css-tables

I'm trying to fix an old table based layout for a client but my html/css skills are only basic...

Could someone tell me how to make this slider extend to about 70% width of the table in IE? (It looks fine in Chrome but IE doesn't play nicely.)

http://www.wcbathshower.com.au/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set a max-width for your #about

```
#about {
            padding: 25px 30px 40px 30px;
            max-width:300px;
        }
```